# Where to place database functionality in web app folder structure such that database has access to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm creating a Node.js and Express web application, and I need a database create operation to be triggered when a users hits a button in the document object model (the user is solving a time-based game, and their time will be submitted to the database after they finish). My current folder structure is below:

[image: project folder structure]

I'm connecting to a MongoDB database instance in **insertData.js**, and the entry point for my app is **app.js**, where I create my Express server. I'm trying to access an HTML element inside **index.html** from **insertData.js**, but I receive the following error when I place the below script tag at the bottom of **index.html**:

`<script src="../insertData.js"> </script>`

[image: HTML Error]

Comment: it's *insertData.js* or *insert-data.js* ?

Comment: Node js is a server side tool so instead of trying to place a file which have access of both `DOM` or `Database or Backend` it is not a good practice instead you should send a `REST` api request to your `server` to store data or whatever you wanted.

Comment: As @VishalBeep suggested, I also prefer to keep frontend and backend in separate projects and have them communicate with REST but there's a very common pattern called Model View Controller (MVC) that essentially contains both frontend and backend in the same project and usually abstracts out the HTTP communication part. Expressjs supports this and it might fit your use case. This article may be helpful in understanding it https://blog.logrocket.com/building-structuring-node-js-mvc-application/

Comment: @ITgoldman It's insertData.js. I realize the error refers to the filename insert-data.js, but I changed the name of the file when I asked this question.

Comment: Thanks @VishalBeep. If I understand your response correctly, are you saying I should send a request through my Express server to store data. Does this involve using routes?

Comment: Thank you @long_hair_programmer. I will read the article on MVC and see if I can restructure my project to align with this pattern.

Comment: @joepianoblaster You can send request from your client (`Javascript`) and in backend Node.js where you are using `Express` handle those requests. And Yeah you have to use `routes` to handle those requests. i.e. `app.post("/api/store_data",(req,res)=>{ // here your code goes })`

Comment: @joepianoblaster if you meant by storing data in `Express` Server than you are thinking wrong. You can't store data in Express or Node Js You have use a Database like - `mongo db` or many other alternatives.